# Database design for cross-linked data

Tags: database, rdbms, nosql

I don't have a lot of experience with NoSQL databases (or even relational DBs, really), so I'm not sure how to design a good storage schema for my data.

In my business logic, I have two main kinds of of objects; let's call them Containers and Items. Each object has a unique ID. An Item can belong to multiple Containers, though most Items will only belong to a single Container. In addition, Items can be linked to each other. There's no relevant metadata for this link, it's just a flag that says, "Items a and b are linked to each other". There are going to be ~20M Containers, each containing ~50K Items on average; however, a few rare Containers will have ~5M Items (and some others will have as few as 100 Items). Containers are rarely deleted or updated, but new Containers (and thus, new Items) will be created about once every few days.

Here is some sample data (I'll use names instead of numeric IDs because IDs are boring):

- Container "A"

  - Item "a1"
  - Item "a2"
  - Item "a3"
- Container "B"

  - Item "b1"
  - Item "b2"
- Container "C"

  - Item "c1"
  - Item "c2"
  - Item "c3"
  - Item "c4"
- Linked Items:

  - Items "a1" and "b1" are linked
  - Items "a3" and "b2" are linked
  - Items "b2" and "c4" are linked
  - Items "a1" and "c2" are linked

I need to answer the following questions relatively quickly (no more than 10s per request, including the time needed to transfer the data; ideally, 1s):

- Given a Container ID, list all Items in that Container, including their Item IDs as well as some metadata for each Item. In this case, if I was asked, "Give me all Items in Container A", I would respond "{(a1,a1.metadata), (a2,a2.metadata), (a3,a3.metadata)}"
- Given two Container IDs, find all the pairs of items that are linked between these two Containers. If I was asked, "Which Items in A are linked to B", I would reply, "{(a1,b1), (a3,b2)}"
- Given a reference Container, find all others Containers that have at least one Item linked to an Item in that reference Container; also, count how many Items are actually linked. If I was asked, "Which Containers contain items linked to A ?", I would reply, "{(B,2), (C,1)}"
- Given an Item, find all other Items that are linked to it. If I was asked, "Which Items are linked to a1 ?", I would reply "{b1, c2}".

Most Containers will have few, if any, Items that are linked between them; however, some Containers would have ~90% of their Items linked.

So... how should I store this data ? My first option was of course to use ye olde SQL relational database, because it's really easy -- you just need to create four tables (e.g., ITEM, CONTAINER, ITEM_CONTAINER_MAP, ITEM_LINK), and you're done. Unfortunately, neither Oracle nor MySQL could handle the sheer volume of data quickly enough. I can't use any AWS infrastructure, so Redshift and DynamoDB are out (our clients are prohibited from using cloud services). So, any ideas ?

My apologies for the long-winded post; unfortunately, I don't even know what it is that I don't know...